# Delphi 2007 - Allowing a Read-only file to be selected in a TSaveDialog

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, readonly-attribute, tsavedialog

I have a need for a user to be able to select an existing read-only file from a save dialog.  I thought you could do this with a judicious selection of the `TSaveDialog`  options but I can't make it happen.  If I select a R/O file, as soon as I hit the `Save` button I get the message:

```
    Read-only.txt
    This file is set to read-only.
    Try again with a different file name.
```

I imagined the option bit `ofNoReadOnlyReturn` would control this, but it seems to have no effect.

What am I missing?

```
program Project1;

uses
  Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

-

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    SaveDialog1: TSaveDialog;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if SaveDialog1.Execute then
    begin
    Windows.Beep (1000, 300) ;
    end ;
end ;

end.
```

-

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 69
  ClientWidth = 195
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 56
    Top = 18
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object SaveDialog1: TSaveDialog
    FileName = 'Read-only.txt'
    InitialDir = 'C:\Users\Ross\Documents\RAD Studio\Projects'
    Options = [ofHideReadOnly, ofNoReadOnlyReturn, ofEnableSizing]
    Left = 16
    Top = 16
  end
end
```

Comment: If the file is read-only, you can't choose it in a **save** dialog, because you can't overwrite the file (it's read-only). If you want the user to be able to overwrite the file, then remove the readonly attribute first before displaying the dialog.. (Hardly makes sense to make the file read-only in the first place when you know you want the user to be able to overwrite it. *I'll make this file read-only to prevent the user from overwriting it. Wait, how do I let the user overwrite the file?*)

Comment: The intention was to reset the R/O flag, allow the overwrite, then set the R/O flag again.  The issue is that the files are marked read-only because we want to prevent "general" users overwriting them, but these files occasionally need to be updated by supervisors (using a program that only they have access to) and I wanted to make that process as painless as possible.

Comment: A little playing around shows that TOpenDialog allows selection of a read-only file, while TSaveDialog does not (regardless of the flags you use in Options). Apparently it's something in the VCL wrapper that's interfering with the ability to choose read-only files with TSaveDialog. Don't know if that's something that will help, but... Also not sure you're aware, so I"ll mention it: You can experiment with the dialogs at design time by setting the options you want in the OI and then double-click the component, which will open the dialog with the current options. It makes testing pretty quick.

Comment: Thanks Ken.  No, I wasn't aware of the design-time preview by double-clicking - very useful, especially if the project takes a while to build and startup.  Eventually, I did use `TOpenDialog`, with code in the `OnShow` event to bend the `Open` button caption to read `Save`

Comment: Yeah, the design-time preview even allows testing file masks and initial directories and the other stuff, not just the options settings. Not everyone is aware, which I thought I'd mention it. It's an extremely useful feature, and works with all of the dialog components (TSaveDialog, TFileSaveDialog, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with `TSaveDialog` itself, but with the underlying Win32 `GetSaveFileName()`/`IFileSaveDialog` APIs that `TSaveDialog` uses internally.  They simply do not allow a read/only file to be the result of a "save" dialog.

That being said, `IFileSaveDialog` does provide a *possible* (albeit ugly) workaround.  If you enable the dialog's `FOS_OVERWRITEPROMPT` flag, then selecting an existing file will prompt the user if the file can be overwritten before closing the dialog.  The `IFileDialogEvents` interface has an `OnOverwrite` event, which is fired before that prompt appears (and can return `FDESVR_ACCEPT` to skip the prompt completely).  So, in that event, you could remove the file's `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY` attribute before the dialog is closed.  However, the dialog will still display the same "This file is set to read-only" error message and refuse to close (presumably because it has checked the attribute before firing the `OnOverwrite` event), but if you then select the same file again, the attribute will have been cleared and the dialog will accept the file (that is the ugly part - you would have to train your managers to ignore that error and retry).

`GetSaveFileName()` has an `ofOverwritePrompt` flag, but no event for overwrite prompting.

That being said, `TSaveDialog` does not expose access to the `IFileSaveDialog.OnOverwrite` event when it uses `IFileSaveDialog` internally, but you can use `TFileSaveDialog` instead, which does.